# Memoizacion en funciones recursivas, javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function fibo(num) {
  if(num == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else if(num == 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return fibo(num-1) + fibo(num-2);
  }
}
```

Este es mi código para resolver fibonacci en javascript, pero hago fibo(50) se queda colgado. He estado investigado acerca de la memoización y como aplicarla en funciones recursivas, pero aun no comprendo me podrian ayudar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aqui esta fibonacci en version memoizacion, que no es simplemente mas que guardar los valores que ya han sido calculados.  Algo asi:

```js
var cache = {1:1, 2:1};
function fib(n) {
    if(!cache[n]) // Ya calculamos este valor?
       cache[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)  // Calcular y guardar

    return cache[n]
}

console.log(fib(50));
```

Comment: ¿qué significa esta línea?  {1:1, 2:1};

Comment: Es la inicializacion de fibonacci.  fib(1) = 1, fib(2) = 1

Comment: ah gracias @alanfcm no lo habia entendido

Comment: Entiendo, osea se crea una especie de memoria a la cual consulto antes de ejecutar la función. Thanks you

Comment: Correcto, te ahorras dobles calculos.

Comment: Pregunta estupida, por que tú IF no tiene parentesis ("{ }")?

Comment: En algunos lenguajes, las llaves {} son opcionales.  Significa que el if solo consiste de una linea.  Si tienes mas de una sentencia, tienen que ir encerradas en llaves.

Comment: Gracias, aunque quise decir llaves.